# Full Page(Or at least almost)JavaScript Lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

First off, as always, jQuery is always a option.

I am looking for a "full screen" lightbox.
I do not mean like fill the entire screen, but more like cover most of the content.
Most of the lightboxes I have seen, use just images, or do not go as big as I want it to go.
Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use colorbox - http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/ .

You can specify the dimesions (even in %'s) in it.

Answer (score 0):

This is something you can easily modify with your styling options... Basically you'll want to set the lightbox to be set as something like this:

```
#lightbox{
position: fixed;
top:1%;
left:1%;
height: 98%;
width: 98%;
}
```

You'll be able to do this either in your style sheet, or there may be an option to set this within the script.